# Android large batch object allocation efficiency

Tags: java, android, performance, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I'm looking for some Android/Java advice. I'm not experienced in the realms of the GC.

The app I'm writing reads a whole bunch of text data at the beginning and then parses it into ~40000 separate (relatively small) objects. I can't reduce them to primitives because of other functionalities and this generates a pretty slow load time (~6 seconds). I think I've hunted it down specifically to the object allocation but I'm now at a loss of how to make it more efficient.

Here's the code that's doing the slow work:

```
protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<Song>... lists) {

    String[] vals;
    long startT = 0, readT = 0, splitT = 0, songsT = 0, doneT;

    try {
        InputStream is = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(fid);
        int dataLength = is.available();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        int dataRead, chunkRead;
        char[] buf = new char[dataLength];

        dataRead = 0;
        startT = System.nanoTime();
        while((chunkRead = reader.read(buf, dataRead, Math.min(4096, dataLength - dataRead))) > 0) {
            dataRead += chunkRead;
            publishProgress((int)(dataRead*6000 / (float)dataLength));
        }
        publishProgress((int)(dataRead*6000 / (float)dataLength));
        reader.close();
        readT = System.nanoTime();

        String[] tokens = Pattern.compile("[\n|\r]+").split(new String(buf));
        splitT = System.nanoTime();
        publishProgress(7000);

        for(String t : tokens) {
            vals = t.split(" - ");
            lists[0].add(new Song(vals[0], vals[1]));
        }
        songsT = System.nanoTime();
        publishProgress(9000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(e.toString(), e.getMessage());
        for (int i = 0, len = e.getStackTrace().length; i < len; ++i) {
            Log.e("StackTrace", e.getStackTrace()[i].toString());
        }
    }

    lists[0].trimToSize();
    doneT = System.nanoTime();
    publishProgress(10000);

    //timing logs
    Log.d("read time", "" + ((readT - startT)/(float)1000000000));
    Log.d("splitting time", "" + ((splitT - readT)/(float)1000000000));
    Log.d("song creation time", "" + ((songsT - splitT)/(float)1000000000));
    Log.d("trim time", "" + ((doneT - songsT)/(float)1000000000));
    Log.d("TOTAL LOAD TIME", "" + ((doneT - startT)/(float)1000000000));
    return null;
}
```

And here's the log it produces that's making me think it's the new object allocations. The end of the log is results of the timing code in the block above. The lions share is object creation.

```
08-13 21:53:52.470  18558-18572/com.example.package D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5070K, 40% free 9834K/16168K, paused 86ms, total 86ms
08-13 21:53:52.470  18558-18572/com.example.package I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 12.110MB for 2568400-byte allocation
08-13 21:53:52.540  18558-18572/com.example.package D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 24% free 12343K/16168K, paused 66ms, total 67ms
08-13 21:53:52.790  18558-18572/com.example.package D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 313K, 26% free 12078K/16168K, paused 76ms, total 77ms
08-13 21:53:52.790  18558-18572/com.example.package I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 14.301MB for 2568400-byte allocation
08-13 21:53:52.880  18558-18567/com.example.package D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 22% free 14586K/18680K, paused 92ms, total 92ms
08-13 21:53:53.380  18558-18572/com.example.package D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 499K, 14% free 16135K/18680K, paused 76ms, total 76ms
08-13 21:53:53.980  18558-18572/com.example.package D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 706K, 7% free 17476K/18680K, paused 105ms, total 106ms
08-13 21:53:54.590  18558-18572/com.example.package D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1552K, 10% free 17775K/19584K, paused 117ms, total 117ms
08-13 21:53:55.270  18558-18572/com.example.package D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1433K, 9% free 18149K/19884K, paused 124ms, total 124ms
08-13 21:53:55.910  18558-18572/com.example.package D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1429K, 9% free 18490K/20260K, paused 129ms, total 129ms
08-13 21:53:56.540  18558-18572/com.example.package D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1337K, 9% free 18900K/20600K, paused 137ms, total 137ms
08-13 21:53:57.190  18558-18572/com.example.package D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1367K, 9% free 19255K/21008K, paused 143ms, total 143ms
08-13 21:53:57.800  18558-18572/com.example.package D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1402K, 9% free 19556K/21364K, paused 146ms, total 146ms
08-13 21:53:58.440  18558-18572/com.example.package D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1260K, 8% free 19980K/21664K, paused 163ms, total 164ms
08-13 21:53:59.070  18558-18572/com.example.package D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5158K, 26% free 16486K/22084K, paused 158ms, total 158ms
08-13 21:53:59.080  18558-18572/com.example.package D/read time﹕ 0.23885109
08-13 21:53:59.080  18558-18572/com.example.package D/splitting time﹕ 0.5500893
08-13 21:53:59.080  18558-18572/com.example.package D/song creation time﹕ 5.6512194
08-13 21:53:59.080  18558-18572/com.example.package D/trim time﹕ 0.1600585
08-13 21:53:59.080  18558-18572/com.example.package D/TOTAL LOAD TIME﹕ 6.6002183
```

I know approximately how much memory the app will use once it's finished loading and how many objects it has to allocate. Would either of these things be useful in reducing the amount of time spent on allocation? Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you really need all 40k objects at the same time? Perhaps you could look into only instancing maybe 1000 and reusing them with some sort of Object Pool implementation.

Comment: let your Text file be persisted on Storage and read them in bits maybe by line or by your preference create and save your tiny objects to let's say 20, when you are in need of more clear away  the in-memory 20 and replace it with the next 2o to be read. pretty easy

Comment: I also need to be able to search the entire batch on a frequent basis. Can this also be efficiently accomplished when only keeping a small pool and consistently reading them from the file? I'm just trying to cut down start time. Total memory usage is only about 16M, which doesn't seem bad to me.